# 3 and 1 being interpreted as strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, numbers, replit

I am making a dice rolling program where you try to have a dice roll higher than the computer, although it is completely randomized. I have the function:

```
def wait(loop, time):
    sleep(time)
    for number in range(loop):
        print('.')
        sleep(time)
```

That is inteded to cause a ... appear for waiting.

Sample input:

```
wait(3, 1)
```

Intended output:

```
.
.
.
```

Where it loops 3 times, and waits 1 second between each loop. I am getting the error

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I don't understand because it is a number not a string.

I have tried using int() on every part and only some parts For example:

```
def wait(loop, time):
    sleep(int(time))
    for number in range(int(loop)):
        print('.')
        sleep(int(time))

wait(int(3), int(1))
```

and

```
def wait(loop, time):
    sleep(int(time))
    for number in range(int(loop)):
        print('.')
        sleep(int(time))

wait(3, 1)
```

and

```
def wait(loop, time):
    sleep(time)
    for number in range(loop):
        print('.')
        sleep(time)

wait(int(3), int(1))
```

Comment: Here is the Repl.it link to my code, the error appears in line 29 https://repl.it/@AaronRodriguez2/Die-Roll-v10

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: There's no need to put `int` around the parameters you're passing to `wait`. They're already integers.

Comment: What variable are you passing into that function?  If it's from input() it's possible you're getting more than just the number e.g. whitespace etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem. 
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
An off-site link is not acceptable per Stack Overflow's charter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you assign a string value to `wait` this creates a local variable which over-rides the function with a name of `wait`

```
 wait = input('\nPress enter to begin the game:')
```

You can't then call `wait(3,1)` later because `'\nPress enter to begin the game:'(3,1)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought I tried that, but I forgot to change all of the waits.